# ASP GridView DataBind with Entity Navigated property

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, gridview

I have a GridView DataBind with entity ClassA's properties that is working fine.
I am able to directly bind below properties in ASPX file.
ClassA.Id
ClassA.Name
etc.

But ClassA also have a navigation property to related ClassB. I would like in a the same GridView to display related classB's properties.

I try to bind the following in the GridView but it does not work even if I am able to properly evalute the below value in debug mode (entity performs lazy loading when required).
ClassA.classB.Name

How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achive your goal by a template column with an eval function as below;

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
                Text='<%# Eval("ClassA.ClassB.Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"
            Text='<%# Eval("ClassA.ClassB.Name") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The downside of this approach is disabling the two-way databinding feature by using the late-bound eval method.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It works well but as you said it does not enable 2-way databinding. Do you see any alternative ?

Comment: There are some alternatives such as implementing ITypedlist or IBindingList interface for your data sources. But it is not a trivial task. So you should decide if it is worth to create a custom binding provider.